# Installing ghc-mod from melpa: Error during download request

Tags: emacs, haskell-mode, ghc-mod

I am following the instructions [here](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/preparation.html) to install `ghc-mod` in Emacs. I can add the melpa repos and list packages with `M-x package-list-packages`, then when I go to install the `ghc` package, this happens:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Error during download request: Not Found")
  signal(error ("Error during download request: Not Found"))
  error("Error during download request:%s" " Not Found")
  package-handle-response()
  package-download-tar(ghc "20141130.1848")
  package-download-transaction((ghc))
  package-install(ghc)
  mapc(package-install (ghc))
  package-menu-execute()
  call-interactively(package-menu-execute nil nil)
```

In `.emacs` I have

```
(require 'package)
;; Add the original Emacs Lisp Package Archive
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/"))
; old url for melpa
;(add-to-list 'package-archives
;             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
     '("melpa-stable" . "http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/"))
;; Add the user-contributed repository
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

I am using emacs 24.3.1 on ubuntu. How to proceed? Thanks.

[EDIT] I installed this package successfully by downloading it myself but I'd still like to know what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have started working with MELPA (not MELPA stable):

- You have the MELPA package repository in your `.emacs` (though commented out), and
- The traceback shows that you were trying to install version `20141130.1848`, which is a MELPA-style timestamp.

But MELPA is disabled in your init file by the commenting. You *also* have MELPA stable listed, which uses a [different versioning scheme](https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa#stable-packages) based on Git tags instead of on build timestamps. The [latest version of `ghc` in MELPA Stable](http://stable.melpa.org/#/ghc) is currently `5.2.1.2`.

I think you may have made this change without running `package-refresh-contents`, which updates your local package list. (Note that this is often done automatically, e.g. by loading the package list with `package-list-packages`).

So when you tried to install `ghc`, based on the stale package list that Emacs had it looked for version `20141130.1848`, but could only find version `5.2.1.2`. Try again after running `M-x package-refresh-contents`.

Note that you *also* have Marmalade enabled, which *also* contains `ghc` (version `1.10.2`).

Since there is some package overlap between MELPA and Marmalade, I don't recommend using both concurrently. You can manually pin packages to one repository, but this gets to be a pain. I switched to MELPA Stable exclusively a few months ago, and I've been very happy with it.

Comment: What do you suggest I do to fix the problem?

Comment: @jaybee, decide which package repositories you wish to use and ensure that your config uses only these (I recommend MELPA Stable and the standard GNU ELPA). Get rid of `tromey.com`; GNU ELPA should be included by default. Restart Emacs. `M-x package-list-packages` (which should automatically refresh your local package list; you should see "Contacting host..." messages), find `ghc`, and install.